# How can I know if my NN TensorFlow model is overfitted or not?

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, accuracy, overfitting

I am new with TensorFlow (Python) and I can not juge my obtained results in terms of training and testing accuracy

I am using the GradientDescentOptimizer with a learning coeff equal to 10^(-4) and I have executed the following code :

```
for gg  in range (1501):
    session.run(optimizer, feed_dict=train_data)
    train_accuracy = session.run(accuracy, feed_dict=train_data)
    if gg % 100 ==0 :
        #print(train_accuracy)
        session.run(optimizer, feed_dict=test_data)
        test_accuracy = session.run(accuracy, feed_dict=test_data)
        print(test_accuracy)
```

One time I have commented the testing accuracy to print only the training accuracy and one time I did the contrary. 
I had stored them in the following table: 
  [image: The Table I have obtained]

My problem is that I am not able to detect overfitting if it exists or not
Can you help me please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accuracies do not signal a warning as @Simon points out, but you seem to be training your optimizer with the test data at each 100-th iteration, which makes all our conclusions invalid.

i.e. the line
`session.run(optimizer, feed_dict=test_data)`

Comment: Yes, my answer is moot until this has been fixed. Nice catch! :)

Comment: So what should I do? should I reset the program to try each number of iteration seperatly? I did this and I got the same results like the ones given by this program.

Comment: Frome the above figure which is the best number of iteration I should take?

Comment: You should remove the line `session.run(optimizer, feed_dict=test_data)`. Even if it's gonna be similar, it's better to do it right. If you obtain a similar table, I personally don't think you've reached overfitting point.

Comment: Can you clarify in your answer what should I do if I removed session.run(optimizer, feed_dict=test_data) from the loop should I write it outside of the groupe?      My choice for the iteration number will be based one what? means I will say that the number of iteration was fixed to 800 because of what?

Comment: You will completely remove it, because it tunes your optimizer using the test data. I can't give you an exact number for the iteration but 1500 iterations seems good, if you obtain similar values. Because, the training and test accuracies are close.

Comment: So I remove `session.run(optimizer, feed_dict=test_data)` and I keep        `test_accuracy = session.run(accuracy, feed_dict=test_data)` to get the test accuracy

Comment: Yes! Only remove the `session.run(optimizer, feed_dict=test_data)` line and run again. Don't be surprised if you test accuracy end up being lower. Then you can look at my answer to see if it is overfitting or not.

Comment: Why do I choose 1500 if I am having the same training accuracy for both 500 and 600 iterations does not means that from 600 I will have an overfitting?  Means what should I answer if they asked me why you have choosed 1500 as iterations number?

Comment: Accuracy is not the only thing you seek for. If your cost function stops decreasing then you can of course stop early. To visualize it, think of a binary classification problem with logreg. Lets say you set your threshold at 0.5 and decide class 1 when y > 0.5 and vice versa. Maybe at 500-th iteration your samples cumulate around 0.4 and 0.6, which means you decide correctly but not so surely. At 1500-th iteration, may be your outpus cumulate around 0.8 and 0.2, which means you are more certain when deciding.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, no it does not look like you are overfitting. Your validation (you call this test) accuracy seems to follow your training accuracy quite closely.

Easiest way to check for yourself is to plot the training and validation accuracy over each iteration, then look at how the curves behave. What you want to see is a test curve that closely follows your validation curve.

Overfitting can come in too ways, your validation curve being quite a bit lower than your training curve and/or a validation curve that is decreasing when the training curve is increasing.

Both these behaviors can be seen in this picture:

[image: Plot showing both overfitting and no overfitting]

[Image taken from Stanford's CS231n](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#baby)

**Edit:** As gunes points out you seem to have a programming error that should be addressed before any checks for overfitting.